# Firemonkey Stringgrid Rowlines Draw only as Screen Width

Tags: android, delphi, grid

I'm developing a project using Delphi XE7 UP1 & Delphi 10 Seattle for Android & IOS. Using Stringgrid to show data, on stringgrid i've 7 Columns, until 4th column it fits to screen for other columns i need to swipe left, using AlternatingRowBackground as true, until 4th column system draws ColLines,RowLines and Alternate colors just fine, but when i swipe left to see other columns ColLines,RowLines and Alternate colors gone,i mean there is only column headers and a white page. Please see screenshots :
[from column 1 to 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avdq9.png)
[from column 4 to 7 and lines are gone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXd2u.png)
So i've tried stringgrid1.repaint - StringGrid1.RealignContent - StringGrid1.UpdateEffects - updatecolumns and so on, but nothing worked, as far as i understand system draws row&col lines as far as screen's width. Is there any workaround to keep colors,row&col lines in all grid ?

Thanks in advance,sorry for bad english :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if someone needed in the future, here is the solution

```
procedure TForm1.StringGrid1DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject; const Canvas: TCanvas; const Column: TColumn; const Bounds: TRectF; const Row: Integer; const Value: TValue; const State: TGridDrawStates);
var
  T, T2: TRectF;
begin
  if Row mod 2 = 1 then
  begin
    with Canvas do
    begin
      Fill.Kind := TBrushKind.Solid;
        Fill.Color := $FFF5802D;
    end;

    T := Bounds;
    if TStringGrid(Sender).ColumnCount - 1  = Column.Index then
      T.Right := Self.Width;
    Canvas.FillRect(T, 0, 0, [], 0.5);
  end;

end;
```